# Custom post type tags not showing in search

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, tags

I have a number of custom post types for which the admin can tag each separate posts.
The problem : None of the posts show upon front-end search query with any of the tags...
Is this normal ? have I not configured my custom type properly ?
below my post type registration:

```
$args = array(
'labels'             => $labels,
'public'             => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'show_ui'            => true,
'show_in_menu'       => true,
'query_var'          => true,
'taxonomies'         => array('post_tag'),
'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'enseigne' ),
'capability_type'    => 'post',
'has_archive'        => true,
'hierarchical'       => false,
'menu_position'      => 7,
'menu_icon'          => $theme_url . '/images/enseignes16x16.png',  
'supports'           => array( 'title', 'author', 'editor', 'thumbnail','comments')  );
register_post_type( 'enseigne', $args );
```

Comment: do you  mean that you search for the tag name and you get no results?

Comment: Yes, Mark,That's exactly the issue.. :(
Say that I tagged a custom post with the word 'shop', search the site from the front-end with it,: it returns no results (to illustrate the issue, the tag 'shop' is only used with this given post, which is a custom post type....)

Answer (score 1):

This is normal functionality of wordpress, the default built in search is done only in the title and content of a post.

Comment: HI Mark, & thanks  for your quick headsup.
I thought as much, but haven't found anything on the forum on how to include custom post type content / tags in the front-end search. I'm sure I could use an action hook, but am a really newbie at this.
Any idea to get me started ?
Many thanks,